# Why is a large choice of K lowering my cross validation score?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, random-forest, sample-size, scikit-learn

Playing around with the [Boston Housing Dataset](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_boston.html) and [`RandomForestRegressor`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) (w/ default parameters) in scikit-learn, I noticed something odd: mean cross-validation score *decreased* as I increased the number of folds beyond 10. My cross-validation strategy was as follows:

```
cv_met = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=k, test_size=1/k)
scores = cross_val_score(est, X, y, cv=cv_met)
```

... where `num_cvs` was varied. I set `test_size` to `1/num_cvs` to mirror the train/test split size behavior of k-fold CV. Basically, I wanted something like k-fold CV, but I also needed randomness (hence ShuffleSplit).

This trial was repeated several times, and avg scores and standard deviations were then plotted.

[image: Area of circle ~ K in K-fold cross-validation]

(Note that the size of `k` is indicated by the area of the circle; standard deviation is on the Y axis.)

Consistently, increasing `k` (from 2 to 44) would yield a brief increase in score, followed by a steady decrease as `k` increased further (beyond ~10 folds)! If anything, I would expect more training data to lead to a minor *increase* in score!

#### Update

Changing the scoring criteria to [mean absolute error](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error.html#sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error) results in behavior that I'd expect: scoring improves with an increased number of folds in K-fold CV, rather than approaching 0 (as with the default, '[r2](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html#sklearn.metrics.r2_score)'). The question remains why the default scoring metric results in poor performance *across both mean and STD metrics* for an increasing number of folds.

Comment: Any duplicate records in your folds? This might be due to *overfitting*.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse No, since the Boston Housing dataset does not have duplicate records and ShuffleSplit's sampling does not cause duplicate records.

Comment: It might still indicate overfitting; duplicate records would just have been an easy indicator.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Ok. Still, this is counterintuitive: increasing the train split leads to more overfitting?!

Comment: Well, you have more training examples = more chance of overfitting; less testing examples per fold = more sensitive (higher stddev, too) to decreased performance because of this.

Comment: Also, improve your plotting. Use error bars, to show mean, +- stddev, and min/max. Put k on the other axis.

Comment: I don't think that more training examples increase the chance of overfitting. I plotted a learning curve with this dataset, again using ShuffleSplit (n_splits=300 with various test sizes) and saw consistently increased accuracy as more training examples were made available.

Comment: On the test set, or training?

Comment: The cross-validation score of the curve was strictly increasing

Comment: Could you provide the dimensions of this dataset: #observations, #features.

Comment: You really should plot error bars, with min, max. If your stddev is 0.20, that may mean you have some outliers that are much worse than 0.80-0.20=0.60

Comment: @Jim the features have a shape of (506, 13). For further detail: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_boston.html

Comment: @Anony-Mousse thank you for the error bars suggestion. I realize that this is the conventional representation of this data (and yes, the STD is high), but I feel that this graph best captures the strength of the relationship I'm trying to show. Despite a high standard deviation, the mean score (over ~40 trials) paints a clear picture. We see a clear, almost linear relationship between k and mean cross-validation score for k > 10.

Comment: If the data is skewed (and it probably is) then the mean can be very misleading. Why don't you add the error bars image (*with* min and max, and preferrably even median instead of  the mean) to your question to give us more to interpret?

Comment: I just added a snippet of the simplest-possible code I could write that demonstrates the problem I'm seeing.

Comment: Isn't it error instead of some positive score?

Comment: 1. A note on terminology `ShuffleSplit(n_splits=k, test_size=1/k)` is **not** *cross-validation* (CV). See: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation. 2. You could first reshuffle the observations, then 50%-50%-train-test split the data, do k-fold CV on the train set, then use the test set as validation for the k-fold CV loss estimate. :)

Comment: @Jim RE 1) right, but the next line with `cross_val_score` _is_ CV, right?

Comment: @rep_ho [r2_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html#sklearn.metrics.r2_score) (more is better)

Comment: if it's r^2 then it's error squared, so less is better

Comment: sorry, you are right, more is better and best is 1. But you don't have this issue if you use mean squared or absolute error. So it has to do something with the error term

Comment: @BrianBien sure, but I would replace the line `cv_met = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=k, test_size=1/k)` by `cv_met = KFold(n_splits=k)`. "ShuffleSplit" is called "repeated learning-testing" in the literature, but it is an inferior alternative to k-fold CV.

Comment: @Jim I did try `KFold(n_splits=k, shuffle=True)` as you suggested (emphasis on shuffle=True for this particular dataset), and got similar results. I'm still perplexed as to why cross_val_score is returning 0 or near-0 results when k approaches n, for n samples.

Comment: @Jim p.s it appears that `ShuffleSplit` (with a large number of iterations) can yield a more robust estimate of generalization performance than `KFold`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

r^2 score is undefined when applied to a single sample (e.g. leave-one-out CV).

r^2 is not good for evaluation of small test sets: when it's used to evaluate a sufficiently-small test set, the score can be far into the negatives despite good predictions.

Given a single sample, a good prediction for a given domain may appear terrible:

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
true = [1]
predicted = [1.01] # prediction of a single value, off by 1%
print(r2_score(true, predicted))
# 0.0
```

Increase the size of the test set (keeping the accuracy of predictions the same), and suddenly the r^2 score appears near-perfect:

```
true = [1, 2, 3]
predicted = [1.01, 2.02, 3.03]
print(r2_score(true, predicted))
# 0.9993
```

Taken to the other extreme, if the test size is 2 samples, and we happen to be evaluating 2 samples that are close to each other by chance, this will have substantial impact on the r^2 score, even if the predictions are quite good:

```
true = [20.2, 20.1] # actual target values from the Boston Housing dataset
predicted = [19, 21]
print(r2_score(true, predicted))
# -449.0
```